# Avoiding R CMD Check Note about different formal arguments

Tags: r

I am running into a similar issue as this unanswered question on `R-pkg-devel` about NOTES during [R CMD Check of a package.](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-package-devel/2016q2/000865.html)

Given a function that assigns a function to an object depending on a conditional, R CMD Check throws a note. This function is an example. The function is pulling data objects from the package's internal namespace (data objects that are lookup tables not exported to the user). Depending on the user specified option, different lookup tables and different assignment functions are created and passed out in a list for use elsewhere.

```
get_baseline <- function(bl){
  if(bl == "ell"){
     data <- ell
     keys <- c("race", "age")
     fun <- function(x) rbinom(1, 1, x)
  } else if(bl == "ses"){
     data <- ses
     keys <- c("race")
     fun <- function(x) rbinom(1, 1, x)
  } else if(bl == "program"){
     data <- prog_baseline
     keys <- NULL
     fun <- function() {prog_baseline[sample(rownames(prog_baseline), 1,
                                    prob = prog_baseline$prob), 1:3]}
   } else if(bl == "grade"){
     data <- age_grade
     keys <- "age"
     fun <- function(x){
       if(x %in% age_grade$age){
         probs <- age_grade[which(age_grade$age == x),][-1]
         out <-sample(names(age_grade)[-1], 1, prob = probs)
         out <- convert_grade(out)
         return(out)
      } else{
         return(NA)
       }
     }
    } else{
      stop("Baseline not currently defined. Maybe you can write your own?")
    }
    return(list(data = data, keys = keys, fun = fun))
 }
```

If this is included in an R package, `R CMD CHECK` says:

```
get_baseline: multiple local function definitions for 'fun' with
  different formal arguments
```

I am doing this on R 3.3.3, but this seems to have been around well before. Is there a better pattern for assigning FUN conditionally? Or is this one of those notes to just live with?

Comment: Does this still happen if you just pass `...`to each function?

Comment: Out of curiosity; is there anything wrong with calling B inside the switch?

Comment: This example is slightly different from what I need to do. I actually need to return each FUN= FUN to a different element in a list. It throws the same error as this example, but this example was readily available. I need to return FUN as part of a list object that gets used later somewhere else.

Comment: I don't think you can create and assign multiple function definitions to the same name. You're essentially creating `fun` in the same enclosing environment with different signatures.